# What is the practical use of the words and letters corresponding to the omer count?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer

I understand the daily and weekly sefiros combinations that are mentioned in the Ribbono Shel Olam prayer and relate to the process of refinement on the way to Shavuos. To a large extent these are relatable concepts.

But I also notice that in some siddurim they include the corresponding word of Lamnatzeach, the letter that comes from the middle pasuk, and the word in Ana B'choach that goes with the day count.

What is someone supposed to do with that information, for example that today's count goes with the letter yud and the words ארץ and גאה? Is there some advantage to knowing or paying attention to that, beyond the value of just counting the days?

Answer (score -2):

All of this relates to the specific kavanot that apply to each day of the 49 days of counting the Omer.

Generally speaking, at the seder of Pesach, on the first night, we receive a gift that is described in kabbalistic literature as our middot being properly connected and directed by our mochin.

When the Omer is brought, that connection is withdrawn and the middot are no longer directed by the mochin.

This connection is reestablished gradually through the mitzvah of counting the Omer.

Each day of the Omer is associated with a specific aspect of that reconnection, which is also associated with G-d’s *Great Name* (the one referred to in Kaddish) which is formed from the 42 first letters of the *Ana B’Koach* prayer together with the full portion of the name formed over that week. For detailed explanation of this name of G-d, see Pardes Rimonim by Rabbi Moshe Kordovero, Sha’ar 21 (פרטי השמות), chapters 12-14. And also Sefer Kehillat Yaacov, erech מ״ב and שמ מ״ב by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles, the author of Melo Ro’im.

A second aspect of that reconnection is associated to the 49 words of the chapter of Tehillim said, beginning from after the introductory sentence and the 49 letters of the the middle sentence.

This is explained in detail in Sefer Kitzur Kavanot l’Ramchal in the section Inyan l’Sefirat HaOmer.

Comment: The question was "What is someone supposed to do with that information?" and "Is there some advantage to knowing or paying attention to that?" This just describes what the letters are, while the question is what is the practical use of knowing that day X is associated with letters ABC. This doesn't answer the question